# Error while launching react development env

Tags: reactjs

I opened hyper and gone to my path and then did npm start and got the below error -

[image: error]

Below Error -

```
Failed to compile.

Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\users\DELL\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\DELL\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\users\DELL\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\DELL\my-app\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

webpack compiled with 1 error
```